# The method 'ControlledAnimation' isn't defined for the type 'LogoState'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, dart-pub

```dart
Widget _buildAnimatedLogo() {
    return ControlledAnimation( //<-- The method 'ControlledAnimation' isn't defined for the type 'LogoState'
      duration: widget.logoAnimationTween.duration,
      tween: widget.logoAnimationTween,
      builder: (context, animation) {
        return Transform.rotate(
          angle: animation["rotation"],
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: 10,
            ),
            child: Container(
              width: animation["size"],
              height: animation["size"],
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/images/logo.png",
                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I am using simple_animations: ^3.0.1, not sure if I am using the wrong class **"ControlledAnimation"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You migrated to a newer version.

Change that with **ControlledAnimation -> PlayAnimation.**

[Check the official example](https://github.com/felixblaschke/simple_animations/blob/documentation/example/stateless_animation.md)

Comment: would you give example below , because example link is not working

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the parentheses and braces in the code you pasted are not properly closed. Note that your `_buildAnimatedLogo` method has no closing squirly brace.

If that is not the issue, it looks like the compiler mixed methods and widgets. It thinks `ControlledAnimation` is a method, when it looks like it should be a widget. Try setting a prefix to your `simple_animations` import statement, like this:

```dart
import '.../simple_animations.dart' as simple_animations;
```

then try to call `simple_animations.ControlledAnimation` instead of `ControlledAnimation` directly. Try to see if that makes the task easy for the compiler.